# jquery prev until class doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this `$('.setting-editor').prev('.visibleWrap').show();`

but nothing happened, I think I used the prev() wrongly. Below is my DOM look like

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `.visibleWrap` isn't the previous tag for `.setting-editor`, `.clearfix` is.

As the docs for [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) state:

> Get the **immediately preceding sibling** of each element in the set of
>   matched elements

Try `.siblings('.visibleWrap')` or `.prevAll('.visibleWrap')`.

Comment: @JamesLemon, I my guess if your need is only the previous elements then use `.prevAll()` else `.siblings()` because `siblings` selects all `previous` and `next` elements. Apparently in your case `.prevAll` is better to use

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$('.setting-editor').siblings('div.visibleWrap').show();
```